# Web App key restriction is not working for Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-api

I am using firebase. I want to restrict the API key generated by firebase so that only my domain can use that key. I tried setting up the restriction using the Credentials page of GCP by having HTTP referrers set as `*.domain.com/*`. Even after saving the changes, I am able to access firebase using localhost which should be not allowed according to restriction.

Comment: What you are doing is the correct procedure, the API key shouldn't have been able to access using localhost, that being said, there is a period for replication of permissions, did you wait long enough for it to be replicated? Does this issue also occurs for other API keys or only the one?

Comment: did you find any solution yet why on localhost is working

Comment: yep not working for firebase...